# android memory leak

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

im pretty sure this is a memory leak but no idea how to fix it

screenshot of eclipse memory analyser (Listener is a service started by an activity, airplaneWait is a BroadcastReceiver)

[image]

airplane wait is started in a thread, in Listener's onCreate().

```
private IntentFilter ftrAirplaneModeChanged = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
```

.

```
registerReceiver(airplaneWait, ftrAirplaneModeChanged);
```

cheers for any help,
ng93

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a memory leak. I think it's just an artifact of the memory analyzer presentation of the object.. airplaneWait has a reference to this$0 , which in turn has a reference to the same airplaneWait object, so you're really seeing the same objects over and over here rather than a huge number of different objects. The gui can't differentiate between *"contains a ..."* and *"has reference to a ..."*

One of those is probably an inner class of the other. Non-static inner classes have implicit references to their parents.

Comment: But of course, you should check the identifier (e.g. *0x4623a740*) at the end of each row in that list to see if they really are the same two objects over and over.

Comment: this$0 is always @0x4623ada0 and airplaneWait is always @0x4623a740. is this ok? (i have no idea what those numbers mean)

Comment: forgot to mention theres another 2 BroadcastReceivers and for each this$0 has a different code

Comment: Those @-code are object identifiers, so if you see the same code somewhere else in the same VM, it is the same object. Having two objects is not a problem. If you're looking for memory leaks, you're looking for many many *different*, distinct objects of some class (with different identifiers), much more than should be there by "natural causes". The output of memory analysis programs can be pretty hard to interpret though.